# Guess 2/3 of the average, but your payout is what you initially guessed.

Tags: game-theory

The "Guess $\frac{2}{3}$ of the average" is a game where $k$ people choose a number between 0 and 100 inclusive, and the person with the closest answer to $\frac{2}{3}$ of the average wins. It is clear that there is a Nash equilibrium, in which everyone picks the number 0.

Here's the twist - the payoff that you get for winning is equivalent to the number you picked at the start, divided by how many people picked your number. So you would get 0 dollars. Obviously, you would want to maximise your payoff.

I'd assume that the Nash equilibrium is still 0 dollars. However a rational choice that would yield money is if everybody picked 100 dollars - and so everybody would get 1 dollar.

Is there a better strategy to this game?

Comment: Looks like a prisoners' dilemma to me, only with more players and more options: The best play for any single person is to ruin it for everyone else, pulling us away from something strictly better than the Nash equilibrium.

Comment: You say "...and $\frac{1}{100}$ of that would be $\frac{2}{3}$" but you also say that the prize is the original bid. So I think you mean "...and $\frac{1}{100}$ of the bid would be $1$".

Comment: @Blitzer Thanks - I modified my question